# OMPL encountered an error: The longest valid segment for state space arm_JointModel must be positive

Tags: ros, moveit

This error comes after launch moveit package demo.launch

```
[ WARN] [1686385140.855607848]: Fail: ABORTED: FAILURE
[ INFO] [1686385141.033518544]: Planning request received for MoveGroup action. Forwarding to planning pipeline.

[ INFO] [1686385141.033795810]: Using planning pipeline 'ompl'
[ WARN] [1686385141.042220232]: Goal sampling thread never did any work. Space information not set up.
[ INFO] [1686385141.044761846]: Planner configuration 'arm[RRT]' will use planner 'geometric::RRT'. Additional configuration parameters will be set when the planner is constructed.
[ERROR] [1686385141.044913244]: OMPL encountered an error: The longest valid segment for state space arm_JointModel must be positive.
Space settings:
ModelBasedStateSpace 'arm_JointModel' at 0x7f75700037e0
```

please help me to solve a error ask for required file in comment.

[image: error]

URDF FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.5.1-0-g916b5db  Build Version: 1.5.7152.31018
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot name="OW_arm42v3">
    <link name="world" />
    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="world" />
        <child link="base_link" />
        <origin rpy="0 0 3.142" xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="base_link">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="3.8908E-17 0.04767 -7.8127E-06" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.0171" />
            <inertia ixx="0.005586" ixy="-1.0982E-17" ixz="1.3566E-18" iyy="0.0063123" iyz="-2.5055E-07" izz="0.0055872" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/base_link.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/base_link.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <link name="BS">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0380406710172112 0.0624222716437212 1.70200828973279E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.97190888064709" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00429954770180157" ixy="0.00121409993044422" ixz="-2.33754900717327E-09" iyy="0.00586776056653254" iyz="-9.02195404940386E-10" izz="0.00632240174237383" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/BS.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/BS.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="BJ" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0.1181" rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="BS" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
        <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="1.57" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="BE">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0518944125106651 0.177875 -3.45259213411031E-19" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="4.90664934838919" />
            <inertia ixx="0.119166306829544" ixy="7.12832856210159E-20" ixz="1.41170367633891E-19" iyy="0.0103792262587238" iyz="-6.6483117914141E-19" izz="0.114829512620447" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/BE.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/BE.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="SJ" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="-0.1157 0.0775 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="BS" />
        <child link="BE" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
       <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="1.57" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="EW1">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0709836520418711 0.00984606315843561 -3.12735130856287E-09" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.70811121792676" />
            <inertia ixx="0.003344964276941" ixy="-0.000815500724151719" ixz="-3.32971212844834E-10" iyy="0.00460394948553801" iyz="4.52826957155396E-10" izz="0.00490007893927466" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/EW1.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/EW1.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="EJ" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.35575 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="BE" />
        <child link="EW1" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
      <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="2" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="W12">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0708307470038271 0.130740197026429 -3.09886790789175E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.15968468440729" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0234261873003578" ixy="-0.00584229346606452" ixz="-4.32903230711196E-08" iyy="0.00623786733512577" iyz="-7.26337149502994E-08" izz="0.026052830309967" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W12.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W12.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="W1J" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0.1157 0.07 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="EW1" />
        <child link="W12" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
      <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="1.57" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="W23">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0.0103627029059784 0.00980076113119743 0.0597441688704256" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.83510738804944" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0071632177132756" ixy="0.000186368537764031" ixz="0.00118141035116698" iyy="0.00720216879798446" iyz="-0.0011338270543624" izz="0.00336114973585378" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W23.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W23.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="W2J" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.28575 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="W12" />
        <child link="W23" />
        <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
        <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="2" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <link name="W3Eff">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-2.13404352369339E-20 0.0313987811298326 -7.81553174110383E-06" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="0.542656625657755" />
            <inertia ixx="0.000548242650538083" ixy="4.09479362245092E-22" ixz="7.11795743081048E-23" iyy="0.000736884379592923" iyz="1.40387237136961E-07" izz="0.000548348712436984" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W3Eff.STL" />
            </geometry>
            <material name="">
                <color rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://OW_arm42v3/meshes/W3Eff.STL" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="W3J" type="revolute">
        <origin xyz="0 0.071 0.12" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="W23" />
        <child link="W3Eff" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit lower="0" upper="2.1" effort="300" velocity="0" />
        <safety_controller soft_upper="3.13" soft_lower="0" k_velocity="0" />
    </joint>
    <transmission name="trans_BJ">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="BJ">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="BJ_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <transmission name="trans_SJ">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="SJ">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="SJ_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <transmission name="trans_EJ">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="EJ">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="EJ_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <transmission name="trans_W1J">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="W1J">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="W1J_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <transmission name="trans_W2J">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="W2J">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="W2J_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <transmission name="trans_W3J">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="W3J">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="W3J_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
            <robotNamespace>/</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="BS">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="BE">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="EW1">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="W12">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="W23">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo reference="W3Eff">
        <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
</robot>
```

Comment: @Greenonline I have provided URDF file of robot and screeshot of error. Please let me know if you want any other files.

Comment: @Greenonline - https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24869/problem-with-define-robot-poses-in-moveit-setup-assistant