# Problem with Define Robot Poses (in Moveit Setup Assistant)

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, simulation, urdf, moveit

In this picture, I can use GUI to define any pose of robot. However, I can't drag the slider or enter a number in the box. What is my problem?

[image: Robot Poses]

Comment: maybe the name cannot be blank

Comment: Please edit your post to include details of what you did to create your environment, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: This question, [Cannot define robot poses in MoveIt setup assistant](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/25157/9176), seems to be a similar issue, the solution may help you.

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR

You need to put a name in the **Pose Name:** field. This allows the sliders to operate.

---

From [MoveIt Setup Assistant](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/_images/setup_assistant_panda_saved_poses.png) (the ***emphasis*** is mine):

> ##### Step 5
>
> - Click on the *Robot Poses* pane.
> - Click *Add Pose*. ***Choose a name for the pose***. The robot will be in its Default position where the joint values are set to the mid-range of the allowed joint value range. Move the individual joints around until you are happy and then Save the pose. Note how poses are associated with particular groups. You can save individual poses for each group.
>
> ...
>
> [image: Robot Poses dialog with the Pose Name field filled in]

Comment: No, it is not working for me.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, I don't know what the answer is. Maybe it is a permissions issue, if you are running on Linux. I would suggest doing a fresh install of ROS on a freshly installed Ubuntu virtual machine, just as a sanity check.

Comment: As the comment states above, you probably need to edit your question and provide more details about your setup, otherwise it will be difficult to diagnose the issue, without guessing.