# Cannot define robot poses in MoveIt setup assistant

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, urdf, moveit

I am using ROS Noetic Ninjemys with Ubuntu 20.04. I made a URDF of an end effector. I tried to configure it with MoveIt setup assistant. However, I am unable to adjust the prismatic joint "flange_vertical" while I try to define the robot poses.

[image: Screenshot of MoveIt]

My URDF is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot
  name="endeffector4">
  <link name="world"/>
  
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.050387 0.039686 0.048716"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.1149" />
      <inertia
        ixx="4.1367E-05"
        ixy="-6.866E-14"
        ixz="2.7746E-21"
        iyy="4.3009E-05"
        iyz="1.4022E-22"
        izz="5.6702E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="world_base_link" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link
    name="vertical">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0.0502311372932116 0.00491665820356758"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.00953772572267691" />
      <inertia
        ixx="7.5511917482841E-06"
        ixy="7.3731952992275E-22"
        ixz="2.38714677766247E-23"
        iyy="1.58301414257507E-07"
        iyz="-2.70631615917454E-08"
        izz="7.55042505209247E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/vertical.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.792156862745098 0.819607843137255 0.933333333333333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/vertical.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="flange_vertical"
    type="prismatic">
    <origin
      xyz="0.050387 -0.060076 0.0086904"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="vertical" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0.04"
      upper="0"
      effort="1"
      velocity="0.01" />
    <calibration
      rising="100"
      falling="0" />
      <safety_controller 
        k_position="20" 
        k_velocity="20" 
        soft_lower_limit="0.03" 
        soft_upper_limit="0.0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="horizontal">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.014525 -1.569E-08 0.028652"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.0063234" />
      <inertia
        ixx="3.8486E-06"
        ixy="1.1544E-12"
        ixz="8.5999E-08"
        iyy="3.8887E-06"
        iyz="-2.2122E-12"
        izz="1.1115E-07" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/horizontal.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.79216 0.81961 0.93333 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://endeffector4/meshes/horizontal.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="vertical_horizontal"
    type="revolute">
    <origin
      xyz="0 0.09 0.005"
      rpy="-0.0056389 0 3.1416" />
    <parent
      link="vertical" />
    <child
      link="horizontal" />
    <axis
      xyz="1 0 0" />
    <limit
      lower="-3.14"
      upper="1.5708"
      effort="30"
      velocity="3.14" />
  </joint>
</robot>
```

There is no error. When I try to visualise the URDF with rviz, the joint moves as expected. I tried changing the limits of the prismatic joint, but that didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I adjusted the **upper/lower** limits, I was able to control the Prismatic joint:

[image]

```xml
  <joint
    name="flange_vertical"
    type="prismatic">

    <origin
      xyz="0.050387 -0.060076 0.0086904"
      rpy="1.5708 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="vertical" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 1 0" />
    <limit
      lower="0.04"
      upper="100.0"
      effort="1"
      velocity="0.01" />
    <calibration
      rising="100"
      falling="0" />
      <safety_controller 
        k_position="20" 
        k_velocity="20" 
        soft_lower_limit="0.05" 
        soft_upper_limit="90.0" />
  </joint>
```